# Custom OPENGL camera view

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I would like to create a custom camera projection. What i mean is how to create custom window which is not in rectangular shape. As in picture below

[image]

You can imagine it as if you are looking through keyhole that 4 constant corner. However i am very confused where should i start to implement the desired effect.

```
Transform transform;
Camera camera(glm::vec3(-5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), 90.0f, (float)DISPLAY_WIDTH/(float)DISPLAY_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
```

Here is typical camera init for opengl which there are no parameter that i can manipulate. I thought maybe i could put a black mesh just in front of my camera to create the affect but it sounds so mundane. Is there any way manipulate it with parametrically.

Comment: You can create frustum of your desired width and height. For that second one, just rotate the camera in clockwise direction by 90 degree

Comment: Is it now about creating a non rectangular window or about rendering a non rectangular region into a rectangular window?

Comment: It seems like your desired effect is not strictly a camera issue. Have you tried to use a 'regular rectangular' camera and to draw 4 (black?) triangles in the corners with disabled z-buffer and transformation matrices (set to the identity matrix)? If you set all transformation matrices to identity, the corners of the screen have the coordinates (+-1, +-1), i.e. the screen is the square with side length 2 around the center (0,0)